# Sending attachments with multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer, nodemailer

**Update:**
What I have tried so far

```
app.post('/jobs/join-us', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      // `file` is the name of the <input> field of type `file`
      var old_path = files.file.path,
          file_size = files.file.size,
          file_ext = files.file.name.split('.').pop(),
          index = old_path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
          file_name = old_path.substr(index),
          new_path = path.join(process.env.PWD, '/uploads/', file_name + '.' + file_ext);

      fs.readFile(old_path, function(err, data) {
          fs.writeFile(new_path, data, function(err) {
              fs.unlink(old_path, function(err) {
                  if (err) {
                      res.status(500);
                      res.json({'success': false});
                  } else {
                      res.status(200);
                      res.json({'success': true});
                  }
              });
          });
      });
  });
```

I have a contact form, where people can apply for a job, this requires uploading a CV to my site.
How can i send attachments with nodemailer and multer?
My app.js for sending emails:

```
app.post('/jobs/join-us', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);

  const output = `


      <p>You have a new message from contact form.</p>
      <h3>Contact Details</h3>
      <ul> 
        <li>Role: ${req.body.role}</li>
        <li>First name: ${req.body.first_name}</li>
        <li>Last name: ${req.body.last_name}</li>
        <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
        <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
        <li>Agreement: ${req.body.agreement}</li>
        <li>Referer: ${req.body.referer}</li>
        <li>CV: ${req.files}</li>

      </ul>
      <h3>Message</h3>
      <p>${req.body.description}</p>
    `;
  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: 'xx', // generated ethereal user
      pass: 'xx',
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });
```

I also tried to add console.log(req.files) under app.post but it seems to be returning nothing, can anybody offer me guidance?

Comment: Edited OP what i've so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell multer which field name is responsible for handling the file upload, take a look at the following example:

HTML:

```
<form action="/jobs/join-us" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input name="role" type="text">
    ...
    <input type="file" name="cv">
</form>
```

Express:

```
app.post('/jobs/join-us', upload.single('cv'), function (req, res, next) {
    ...
});
```

Note: if you want to upload only one file then it's preferable to use `single()`, `array()` method is designed to handle multiple file upload

NodeMailer:

You create the transporter object but you forget to use it in order to send an email with the uploaded file in attachment:

```
transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'foo@example.com',    // sender
    to:   'bar@example.com',    // receiver
    subject: 'Contact Details', // Subject
    html: output,               // message body
    attachments: [
        {
            filename: req.file.originalname,
            path: req.file.path
        }
    ]
}, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
})
```

Comment: It returns the file when i try console.log(req.file) but doesn't include in attachments.

Comment: Don't firget ```enctype="multipart/form-data"``` in the html form, otherwise it won't work

Comment: @wa7d you are right, I will update my answer, thanks